# "Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit'" error when I load my aspx login page

Tags: asp.net

When I run my home page then I got this error. What is the solution of this error?

```
Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its
dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT:
 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
```

Comment: [Install the `AjaxControlToolkit`](https://www.google.nl/#q=install+AjaxControlToolkit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove your temp file from below path.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files

Comment: Thanks #Vishal It's Working